# facebook invited users from app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph Api to make users send requests to their friends on facebook to join my rails application 
I am using these code and Its working great

```
    $("a#invitefriends").click(function(){
        FB.init({
     appId  : 'myAppId',
    cookie :false,
     status :true
   });
  FB.ui({method :"apprequests",message :'my message '});
    });
```

I wanted to get the data of users that the user invited them to my rails app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback method. You can find more information,syntax @

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/canvas-games/requests/